# How to style asp:DropDownList with max-width=100% in asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net

I could use some help with the styling of my DropDownList and set it to max-width: 100%. Have tried multiple things, but nothing seem to work. What i have tried so far are:

```
input {
max-width: 100%;
border-radius: 0 !important;
}
```

Input did not work on the Asp:DropDownList, but worked fine with the Asp:TextBox. I don't want to set the width in pixels like Width="100px", because it should resize itself, because it is responsive.

Have also tried with:

```
DropDownList {
max-width: 100%;
}
```

**Code**

```
<div class="contentbooking">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="CheckinLabel" runat="server" Text="Check-in Date"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="CheckoutLabel" runat="server" Text="Check-out Date"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimepicker2" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="RoomsLabel" runat="server" Text="Rooms:"></asp:Label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="rooms">
                        <option>1</option>
                        <option>2</option>
                        <option>3</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="#1:"></asp:Label>
                    <div class="form-inline">

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="adults" CssClass="form-control" max-width="100%" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="childrens" CssClass="form-control" max-width="100%" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Button ID="Button7" runat="server" OnClick="checkForResevation" Text="Check Availability" CssClass="my-btn" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

As you can see in the code, i have two Asp:DropDownLists which should be inline with each-other. What options do i have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<asp:DropDownList />` gets rendered as a `<select>` element. Try amending your CSS to the following:

```
select {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

I can see you're using Bootstrap's `form-inline` class to try and make the two lists inline. Consider using [`form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) instead:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="#1:" CssClass="col-sm-12 control-label" />
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="adults" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="childrens" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does only work if i don't have two DropDownLists on the same line.. you can see that i'm using form-inline.

Is the only solution to set a width in pixels?

Comment: Indeed, but `form-group` should be a child of `form-inline`. If I'm understanding how the markup should render correctly, [`form-horizontal`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) is better suited to your needs -

Comment: This works.. this is just what i want :) thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Id's of your `DropDownList` to style it as required. Firstly I would recommend checking what the Id's are rendered to once on the client side and then style it accordingly. On my local dev the Id's of the `DropDownList` are rendered as follows

```
MainContent_adults
MainContent_childrens
```

So all you need in your CSS is

```
#MainContent_adults,
#MainContent_childrens{
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> i have two Asp:DropDownLists which should be inline with each-other.

means that you want your two ddl be in the same line right? if so, it should work, just change the `max-width` for this `style="width:49%"`

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="adults" CssClass="form-control" style="width:49%" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="childrens" CssClass="form-control" style="width:49%" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The width is 49% because of the padding/borders of the controls, you can set it to 50% but then you should get rid of the two properties

**EDIT**

In response to:

> It don't looks right when the screen size goes in ipad / iphone mode

AFAIK it is the way it should work, from the [Bootstrap Inline form documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline)

> Add .form-inline to your form (which doesn't have to be a ) for
>   left-aligned and inline-block controls. This **only applies** to forms
>   **within viewports that are at least 768px wide**.

A workaround if you want to get the same behavior, use a table instead

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="adults" CssClass="form-control" style="width:100%" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList></td>
        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="childrens" CssClass="form-control" style="width:100%" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>0</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it works, but don't looks right when the screen size goes in ipad / iphone mode.

Comment: I edited my answer to add a workaround, it will always be with a DDL in the left and another in the right, both in the same line, hope it helps